# How to change activities with tabitems?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, tabitem

I'm trying to change activities when pressing a tabitem.

I know how to do this with image buttons that are also on the main activity.
        ImageButton view_tokyo_tizzy_button =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.tokyo_tizzy_button);

```
    imagebuttonid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

So now how can I do this when a tabitem in this is pressed?

With PageOne being the main activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:text="PageOne"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:text="PageTwo"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:text="PageThree"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```